# Cannot save files using xlwings

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, xlsx, xlwings

I am trying to autofit all the columns in an Excel xlsx file in Python 3, but am running into issues with the save() function. Below is the function I am using:

```
import xlwings as xw

def autofit(path): # path = 'C:\...\output.xlsx'

    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
        wb = xw.Book(path)
        for ws in wb.sheets:
            ws.autofit(axis = "columns")
        wb.save()
        wb.close()
```

The autofit works as expected, but it does not look like the file is being saved. In particular, the outputted file does not have the columns autofitted in the directory that the path specifies. I also tried doing wb.save(path) but it does not work. However, if I try a different path within the same directory, then I get the desired autofitted output (e.g. path = 'C:...\output_2.xlsx' rather than path = 'C:...\output.xlsx'). Is there a way that I can get the original file saved without having to create another file with a different name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Entering a path as

```
'C:\...\output.xlsx'
```

potentially has issues since a 'raw' string like this can be misinterpreted as having escape codes.
For example if the path is

```
path = 'C:\new\output.xlsx'
```

the **'\n'** from the directory **'\new'** would be interpreted as a 'new line character. Therefore you should denote the string as raw by using the r' prefix e.g.

```
path = r'C:\new\output.xlsx'
```

or use forward slashes,

```
path = 'C:/new/output.xlsx'
```

However having said that this will affect reading the file just as much so it would appear there are no issues with the path being misinterpreted.
It is good practice to do this either way.

Other than that I can't see any issue the code, it will save the opened file output.xlsx in the same place with adjusted columns.
You could change the save to

```
wb.save(path)
```

but there is no reason this would work where your existing code fails.